# Can I use Arduino 16-bit PWM on only one pin?

Tags: timer, arduino, avr

I have an Arduino Duemilanove on which I would like to use the internal 16-bit timer to do PWM on pin 9 and *not* pin 10 (I have a Wifi shield in my project which requires the use of pin 10).

Is it possible to configure the timer to send a signal on pin 9 but to not touch pin 10?

Comment: You should be able to do PWM output on pins 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, and 11. Why would you think that using pin 9 would touch pin 10?

Comment: Yes, using analogWrite(), but this uses the 8-bit timer. I'm looking to do 16-bit PWM.

Comment: OK, so you're using your own mechanism to do 16-bit PWM. Why would outputting on pin 9 affect pin 10?

Comment: Most of the sample code I've seen online just configures the timer without really configuring pins and the implication is that there will be output on both those pins from that timer... If that's not the case, great :)

Comment: You should post some actual sample code, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can. I used the TimerOne library: http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/Timer1

in `setup()`

```
  Timer1.initialize(5000)
  Timer1.disablePwm(10); //WiServer needs pin 10!
  Timer1.pwm(9, 0); //set up pin 9
```

Comment: Could you summarize *how* you used it?

Comment: @endolith see here: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/arduino/tree/master/SilviaController

Comment: I mean summarize in your answer how to do it, to make it into a good answer instead of just links.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question/7659#7659   http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259